# KMeans: Extracting the parameters/rules that fill up the clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have created a 4-cluster k-means customer segmentation in scikit learn (Python). The idea is that every month, the business gets an overview of the shifts in size of our customers in each cluster.

My question is how to make these clusters 'durable'. If I rerun my script with updated data, the 'boundaries' of the clusters may slightly shift, but I want to keep the old clusters (even though they fit the data slightly worse).

My guess is that there should be a way to extract the paramaters that decides which case goes to their respective cluster, but I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: What exactly do you want to keep? The way K Means work the clusters will change every time you run it based on the data. You could store your cluster predictions for each item in your data.

Comment: Lets say I have 2 dimensional data, where everything below x = 0.1 and above y = 0.9 becomes labeled as cluster 1. New data comes in, the algorithm retrains, and now a case that is above 0.85 also becomes labeled as cluster 1. This I want to prevent, I want to keep the old rules so that I don't have to continiously investigate the 'meaning' of a cluster. I accept the loss in goodness of fit.   I asked this question somewhere else as well, and there I was adviced to record the mean of every cluster, and look at how new cases are closest to these means.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer in a different topic:

Just record the cluster means. Then when new data comes in, compare it to each mean and put it in the one with the closest mean.