# Inequalities that fill up kmeans clusters

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

Is it possible to obtain the set of inequalities/rules that would make an observation fall into a specific cluster in k means? By inequalities/rules I mean a **set** of inequalities for each coordinate to satisfy in order to fall in to an specific cluster.

I know KMeans works by minimizing distances between the centroids and the oberservations, so that is why I am not sure if what I am asking has been implemented.

I'm using the Kmeans module in sklearn.cluster

Something similar was asked here: [KMeans: Extracting the parameters/rules that fill up the clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631944/kmeans-extracting-the-parameters-rules-that-fill-up-the-clusters)

Comment: Do you mean you have many dimensions/features, and you want to use all of them for clustering? Or, do you have some rules for clustering data(something like decision trees)?

Comment: Thanks @ShahabRahnama for the response. No, I mean if is there a set of intervals (one for each coordinate) so that for every vector (x1,x2,x3,x4) (in R^4 for example) i could evaluate if the coordinates fall into those intervals. This just to see  if I were to have a new observation, on which cluster will it fall.

Comment: @Mangostino Once you have a new vector you can compute the distance to all the cluster centers. The cluster at the smallest distance, the nearest cluster, should be assigned. You can also use the fit_predict() method for this.